# How to check for duplicate names, but avoid activating on itself

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have form in which user have to enter company name, to avoid duplicates I wrote `On_Exit event` for data entry field. It checks all the records and if it finds duplicate it notifies user. Problem is that I use same form for entered data viewing and then doing it same `On_Exit event` shows duplicate warning despite entry not being duplicate. It happens because code check for all entries and since it is already in database it founds itself and raises false alarm, it is a code flaw, but I have no idea how to avoid. Can somebody offer clever way to avoid this problem without creating two identical forms (except one without duplicate checking)?

My code for duplicate checking:

```
Private Sub Pareisk_pav_Exit(Cancel As Integer)

Dim Par_pav As String
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim Counter As Long

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblPareiskejai")

Do Until rst.EOF
    Par_pav = rst(1)
        If rst(1) = Me.Pareisk_pav.Value Then
           Me.WarningLB.Caption = "Entry with this name already exist"
           Exit Do
        Else
            Me.WarningLB.Caption = ""
        End If
    rst.MoveNext
Loop

Exit Sub
```

I have tried to implement Counter in my code to ignore first match, but in this case it catches only second duplicate then entering new entry.

Counter solution (not working as intended) I have tried:

```
Do Until rst.EOF
    Par_pav = rst(1)
        If rst(1) = Me.Pareisk_pav.Value Then
            Counter = Counter + 1
            If Counter = 2 Then
                Me.WarningLB.Caption = "Entry with this name already exist"
                Exit Do
            End If
        Else
            Me.WarningLB.Caption = ""
        End If
    rst.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: You could use the _BeforeUpdate_ event.

Comment: Could always do a selection from the relevant table filtered on the value. If the count of the returned recordset > 0 then you have at least one duplicate! In addition, the number of returned records tells you how many. In other words, why try to do in many lines of VBA code what you can do with native database functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suddenly come up with a solution myself. Since new entry gets new ID even before saved I thought I can use it in my advantage and added  `And rst(0) <> Me.ID.Value` to my `if` clause. So far it works fine. Full edited code:

```
Private Sub Pareisk_pav_Exit(Cancel As Integer)

Dim Par_pav As String
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim marker As Boolean

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblPareiskejai")

Counter = 0

Do Until rst.EOF
    Par_pav = rst(1)
        If rst(1) = Me.Pareisk_pav.Value And rst(0) <> Me.ID.Value Then
            Me.WarningLB.Caption = "Name already exist!"
            Exit Do
        Else
            Me.WarningLB.Caption = ""
        End If
    rst.MoveNext
Loop

Exit Sub

End Sub
```